Fixing issue with copy-paste with AccSupp
I am preparing a math-heavy document and am using the AccSupp package to control what is copied and pasted (for example, $\angle ABC$ usually results in \ABC being copied, but I have it set to copy "angle ABC" instead.)
In order to do this, I'm using: \newcommand{\ang}[1]{$\BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={angle #1}} \angle {#1} \EndAccSupp{}$}.
It works fine, unless the angle is at the end of a line, in which case it refuses to highlight that, instead moving onto the next line.
Is there any way this can be resolved?
Sample:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\newcommand{\ang}[1]{$\BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={angle #1}} \angle {#1} \EndAccSupp{}$}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \ang{ABC} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \ang{DEF} Nam metus odio, laoreet varius convallis...

\end{document}



you should make a small but complete example that can be tested.

Which pdf viewer do you use? Is the behavior the same in other viewers?

When I use Adobe on your MWE, neither angles ABC nor DEF highlight; however, both copy paste properly, with the word "angle".

not much you can do, the reader decides about highlighting, other reader do not highlight the angles at all. Side remark: avoid spaces between symbol and the accsupp commands, in this example it doesn't matter, but in other case the begin and end could end up on two different pages and that is not allowed.
